# NestJS swagger-ui-express package is missing after deploy

Tags: swagger, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I am using `NestJS` version `7.1.0` and `serverless` and creating api document uses `nestjs swagger`. In local it's worked like champ but after deploy got error.

```
swagger-ui-express package is missing
```

I see some issue here but still not resolve this issue.
https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/277

This is my `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.1.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.7",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^4.5.8",
    "aws-serverless-express-binary": "^1.0.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.2.3",
    "class-validator": "^0.11.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.24",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "dynamodb-data-types": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jwks-rsa": "^1.6.0",
    "latinize": "^0.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.26",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "serverless-dynamodb-local": "^0.2.39",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.4",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.4",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3",
    "winston": "^3.2.1"
  },
```

This is the config:

```
const options = new DocumentBuilder()
  .setTitle("My APIs")
  .setDescription("APIs description")
  .setVersion("1.0")
  .addTag("cats")
  .build();

const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
SwaggerModule.setup("api", app, document);
```

Any help!

Answer (score 14):

My solution was to install express:

```
npm i express
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solutions, hope this help someone.
I add a fake endpoint to make sure `swagger-ui-express` not be removed after `webpack` ran.

```
if (event.path === "/api") {
    event.path = "/api/";
} else if (event.path.includes("/swagger-ui")) {
    event.path = event.path.replace("/swagger-ui", "/api/swagger-ui");
}

// Fake to keep swagger-ui-express work after deploy
if (event.path === "/fake-swagger-ui-express") {
    swaggerUi.setup(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to run:

*yarn install*

to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Do you happen to be using yarn workspaces? I had the same problem just now, where locally everything worked but broke on our cluster.

If yes, then try adding this to the package.json of your API that is using the swagger module:
`"workspaces": { "nohoist": ["swagger-ui-express"] }`